# GeoServer imageIOCache warning won't go away

Tags: geoserver, cache

We are running GeoServer 2.15 and we keep seeing this warning message on some pages saying "The "Coverage Access" page "ImageIO Cache Memory Threshold" is unset, and can cause a severe performance penalty when seeding tiles. A value of 1024K should suffice for the most common tile sizes."

While there doesn't seem to be a "Coverage Access" page, there is a "Raster Access" page with a setting for "ImageIO cache memory threshold (KB)" but no matter what we set that to and click Submit, the warning refuses to go away. What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: I am seeing this with version 2.18. This instance has hundreds of layers and had been upgraded in-place for several GeoServer versions.